# Finding payments in contributions

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

Relating to 4.7. It is possible for a contribution to be made up of multiple payments.

A contribution can have a Transaction ID, but individual payments can also have a Transaction ID.

However, individual payments can not be found by searching for 'Transaction ID' in the Contributions > Find Contributions page.

For example: a participant registers for an event, choosing a ticket for £5 and paying online. This creates a contribution with a Transaction ID. We then upgrade the ticket in the back end, to £10. They pay the difference over the phone. We 'Add payment' on the contribution, and record the transaction ID.

Is there any way to search for payments rather than just the parent contributions? If not, perhaps the Find Contributions page should also search (or have an option to search) individual payments too?

For those visually inclined people:

[image: Screenshot example]

Answer (score 3):

You're asking for the fabled "Line Item Search" feature!

In short - this is a tragedy of the commons.  It's cheaper for folks to build a custom search for their particular use case than to fund this feature - and so while several folks have expressed interest in this feature, it's yet to be funded.

If you think you have resources (time or money) to put toward implementing this feature, please contact the CiviCRM core team!

Comment: Hi Jon - I think this might be a different issue. I'm asking about payments as part of contributions rather than line items. Ie: if a contribution becomes 'partially paid' and you record a second payment. I'll update my question with some more detail!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement and I decided that the easiest option was to use one of the bookkeeping reports and link it to the contribution view.

Specifically, what I did was

1. Review the bookkeeping report (mine was instance 18, yours may be different). I needed to modify it slightly so I could filter by contribution id, but this was 4.4. Any bookkeeping type report that can be filtered by contribution id should work.
2. added a bit of code to my existing custom extension that added a link to the bookkeeping report to the contribution view page, filtering by that contribution id. I used the pageRun hook and calculated the report url with the added query string:

`reset=1&force=1&contribution_id_op=eq&contribution_id_value=196673`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution Alan. I've opened an issue about this - I think ideally the 'transaction ID' search should just find all payments in a contribution. If I get time I'll take a crack at implementing it. Issue  here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17808

Answer (score 1):

Recent improvements on CiviCRM allow to achieve this anoying challenge. You can find how to solve this question at [Searching Payments in Civi](https://civicrm.org/blog/eileen/searching-payments-civi) Eileen's blog post.