# Search for Transaction ID of CiviEvent Sub-Contribution

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

Sometimes we'll have someone pay X amount via credit card (Paypal Pro) and register online for an event. Then, they'll call us, and we'll add additional options to the event (via Change Selections), and then run a credit card transaction against the main balance. This works fine.

However, we are having issue searching for the second transactions ID via standard civi searches. Any suggestions? Our accountant uses this for reconciliation.

Similar: [Finding payments in contributions](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8710/finding-payments-in-contributions)

Bug (no updates in awhile): https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17808

CiviCRM 5.5 Drupal 7.x

Possible Solution:

https://civicrm.org/extensions/extended-reports

The Extended BookKeeping Report allows for searching by Transaction # civicrm/report/contribution/bookkeeping_extended

Answer (score 2):

We created an extension that adds Search Payments functionality, as well as a Payments section to Advanced Search: https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.findpayments

HTH.

Comment: This looks awesome, I installed it without a problem. Does it search for transaction ID's for recurring payments or installments?

Comment: It should allow both.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the extension!